# Tag header within section

Tags: html, tags

Is a good practice put the `<header>` tag within the `<section>` one?
I know it's correct within `<header>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`.

`<section>` has used to separate different themes of our page and often we might find `<article>` within that (perhaps with their `<header>`). Then my doubt about the correctness of using the `<header>` tag into the `<section>`.

for e.g.

```
<body>
 <header>
  <hgroup>
   <h1>hello</h1>
   <h2>world</h2>
  </hgroup>
 </header>
 <section>
  <header>Total news</header>
  <article>
   <header><h1>News</h1></header>
   <section>
    <header>Daily news</header>
    <article>
     <header><h2>News 1 title</h2></header>
     <p>news 1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
     <header><h2>News 2 title</h2></header>
     <p>news 2</p>
    </article>
   </section>
  </article> 
 </section>
 <section>
  <header><h1>Another section</h1></header>
  <article>
   <p>Content of another section</p>
  </article>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <p>Copyright</p>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: The HTML5 tags were designed to make it easier for search engines to get through content for starters. Dont see a section as a wrapper, cause thats what I see in your content. I think using headers should be avoided, but thats my oppinion. Check this site for more info. http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/

Answer (score 0):

Your first header `<header>Total news</header>` would be a simple `<H1>`.

The `<header><h1>News</h1></header>` would be `<hgroup><h1>News</h1></hgroup>` (In this example you dont really need that container)

You also should think about your usage of Tags. You don't have to use all of them just because it's the 'correct order'. The less tags you use, the better.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly appropriate to put the `<head>` tag inside a `<head>` tag and it is even recommended according to this article http://www.anthonycalzadilla.com/2010/08/html5-section-aside-header-nav-footer-elements-not-as-obvious-as-they-sound/.
The `<article>` tag can also be put inside a `<section>` tag based on this article http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/.